# How to tell if an html tag in vue is a custom tag or not?

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue and I'm looking at an existing code that makes me question, where do the tags `<u-col>` and `<u-row>` come from?

My very little understanding of Vue so far is that you can create custom components and then use those components like html tags in the template. But my understanding is that if the component is to be used then it must be exported from where it is created and then imported at where it is being used.

Below is a part of the code that I'm not sure if `<u-col>` or `<u-row>` are custom made tags or if they're simply default vue tags? I don't think they're custom tags because I don't see any imports and I haven't found anything in the source code that tells me they are custom tags. But I don't think they are default vue tags either because I haven't seen them from my google searches. The closest I've come to is the `<b-col>` tag but I know that is from bootstrap.

```
<template>
  <u-row class="mb-4 flex-nowrap">
    <u-col class="text-sm text-700 text-right col-2 mr-4">
      <span v-if="required" class="text-warning">*</span>{{label}}
    </u-col>
    <u-col>
      <slot />
    </u-col>
  </u-row>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    label: {
      type: String
    }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: They can be declared globally, in an mixing, plugin etc

Comment: @Estradiaz, if they are declared globally where would those kind of things be normally declared at?

Comment: If it's a vue-cli project, it would generally be done in `main.js` or where `Vue` is initialized.

Comment: The relevant documentation is at https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html